# Random widgets daily

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to display a random widget from a list of three widgets on my application every day. What is the best way to achieve this? Here are the three widgets:

```dart
  Container(
      child: Text("1"),
      color: Colors.red,
  ),
  Container(
      child: Text("2"),
      color: Colors.black,
  ),
  Container(
      child: Text("3"),
      color: Colors.blue,
  ),
```

Comment: You'll need to look up something like SharedPreferences to ensure the app has the same random choice throughout the day.  Just pick 1 of 3, save that with today's date, and as long as today's date is the same, keep the same choice.